# Using LocalStorage to store my array of checkbox checked Values and Retrieving it On Page Refresh

Tags: javascript

I am working on a page with a list of checkbox in my contact form.
What I want to do with my input values is I want to store this on a localStorage key. When I tried to do it, it worked. It was submitted to confirm page. But when I went back to my previous page, the checked input checkboxes were really checked. But when I try to uncheck the checked checkbox, the value is still saved in my localstorage but it went down to the last element of my array.

Here is my html structure:

```
<input
     id='item3'
     name='check-item'
     value='Item1'
     type='checkbox'
/>
<input
     id='item3'
     name='check-item'
     value='Item2'
     type='checkbox'
/>
<input
     id='item3'
     name='check-item'
     value='Item3'
     type='checkbox'
/>
```

here are also my javascript codes:

```
var boxes, arr;

        // This function loads the array and then checks the uid of each checkbox
        // against it.

        function checkBoxes() {
        var getArr = loadBoxArray();
            $.each($('input[name=check-item]'), function (i, el) {
                for(var ctr=0; ctr<getArr.length; ctr++){
                    if ($(this).val() === getArr[ctr]) {
                        $('input[value='+getArr[ctr]+']').prop('checked', true);
                    } else {
                        $('input[value='+getArr[i]+']').prop('checked', false);
                    }
                }
            });
            
        }

        // If the localStorage item is available, load it into an array
        // otherwise set a default array and save it to localStorage

        const loadBoxArray = () =>{
        if (localStorage.getItem('boxes')) {
            arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('boxes'));
            return arr;
        } else {
            arr = [0, 2];
            saveBoxArray(arr);
            return arr;
        }
        }

        // Save the array to localStorage    

        function saveBoxArray(arr) {
            arr = [...new Set(arr)]
            localStorage.setItem('boxes', JSON.stringify(arr));
        }

        // On page load check the boxes found in localStorage

        checkBoxes();

        // Clicking a checkbox will update the checkbox array which is then saved to localStorage

        $('input[name=check-item]').click(function () {
            var arr = $.map($('input[name=check-item]:checked'), function (el) {
                return $(el).val();
            });
            saveBoxArray(arr);
        });
```

What could be wrong in my code? I am working on this for almost 4hrs already and I haven't solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

use while loop, instead of for loop. hope its helps you solve your current issue. thanks!

Comment: Not sure this would effect what he is trying to save.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How will this make a change? i think it is the same when using for loop though. @Lance

Comment: for loop starts from the beginning and dumps your last item in the end,  but for while loop performs exact opposite. im not sure whether its sort your issue or not but worth to try. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage can only save simple objects.  Convert the array to a JSON string first.

[Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)